# Is anybody using the Database Unit Test tools in Visual Studio 2010? What alternatives are there?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, database-project

I'm working on a project with a fairly large SQL Server database. The schema for the database is already in a Visual Studio Database project which I mostly use to track schema changes in source control. This means I am already able to deploy an empty database for testing relatively easily.

The views, stored procedures and functions in the database contains a fair bit of logic, and I want to write some unit tests for that logic.

My questions are the following:

1. In Visual Studio 2010 there is a template and functionality for a "Database Unit Test". Is anybody else using this functionality with any success?
2. Are there other better or more widely used alternatives for specifically testing logic in SQL Server stored procedures, views and functions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using database unit tests in Visual Studio 2010 (Premium Edition).  There has been some success.  We've decided to wrap all of our tests in a transaction that gets rolled back at the end so that we don't leave test data in the database.  I did find one defect related to comparison when evaluating unique identifiers, but overall it's been easier to maintain than T-SQL Unit which is what we used before.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have also since started trying out the database unit tests and I am relatively happy so far.